# Can't change column width and margin when layout=fixed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I try to set column width ona particular column but it doesn't work. My table is `layout=fixed` and `width=100%`. I set `max-width=300px` for one of the columns but nothing changes, all columns are distributed evenly in a table. My table is not responsive as to fix column width.

**CSS:**

```
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <table class="table table-hover ml-3 mr-3">
      <tr class="headers bg-primary text-white headers">
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Account)
         </th>
         <th>
             @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Day)
         </th>
      </tr>

   <tbody id="myTable" class="align-middle">

      <tr>
         <td style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space:normal">
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
         </td>
         <td style="max-width: 300px">  <!-- here I set column width  -->
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Account)
         </td>
         <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Day)
         </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Adding `style="max-width: 300px"` to `<th>` also doesn't help.
Also `ml-3` and `mr-3` works bad, I have only margin added on left. Additionally horizontal scroll bar appears at the bottom of a table.

this is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max-width` property only applies to block elements, so you need to apply it `display: block`:

```
<td style="max-width: 300px; display: block; margin: auto;">
 XYZ
</td>
```

```css
table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    tbody > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
   <table class="table table-hover ml-3 mr-3">
      <tr class="headers bg-primary text-white headers">
         <th>
             Name
         </th>
         <th>
             Account
         </th>
         <th>
             Day
         </th>
      </tr>

   <tbody id="myTable" class="align-middle">

      <tr>
         <td style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space:normal">
             XYZ
         </td>
         <td style="max-width: 300px; display: block; margin: auto;"> <!-- here I set column width  -->
             XYZ
         </td>
         <td>
             XYZ
         </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: But I tested your code with this rule and I got it. The maximum width of the specified cell did not exceed 300 pixels.

Comment: Take a screenshot from cell where display: inline-table;

Comment: ok, look at this fiddle I created, it doesn't work here: https://jsfiddle.net/7rhsn81p/1/

Comment: I added screenshot to my first post

Comment: Yes, I was wrong in the first solution and completely forgot that `max-width` is only for `block` elements. I have updated the answer. Check.

Comment: always glad to help!